# How do I properly define an object using a class?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Have searched for hours to understand why this is happening before coming on here to ask. Please help me understand how to use the class / object properly. Thank you in advance for your help and patience.

HERE IS THE ERROR

line 46, in

print("Brains: ", hero.brains)

AttributeError: 'Superhero' object has no attribute 'brains'

```
#Importing Random Module

import random

#create Superhero class

class Superhero():
    #initializing our class and setting its atrributes
    def _init_(self):
        self.superName = superName
        self.power = power
        self.braun = braun
        self.brains = brains
        self.stamina = stamina
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.constitution = constitution
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.speed = speed

# adding random values to each

braun = random.randint(1,20)
brains = random.randint(1,20)
stamina = random.randint(1,20)
wisdom = random.randint(1,20)
constitution = random.randint(1,20)
dexterity = random.randint(1,20)
speed = random.randint(1,20)


print("Please enter your Super Hero name: ")

# creating the super hero object
hero = Superhero()

# assigning a value to superName using the user's input
hero.superName = input('>')

# print the result of the created object, including its parameters

print("Your name is %s. " % (hero.superName))
print("Your new stats are: ")
print("")
print("Brains: ", hero.brains)
print("Braun: ", hero.braun)
print("Stamina: ", hero.stamina)
print("Wisdom: ", hero.wisdom)
print("Constitution: ", hero.constitution)
print("Dexterity: ", hero.dexterity)
print("Speed: ", hero.speed)
print("")
```

Comment: All your variables `braun`, `brains`, `stamina`, etc. need to be INSIDE the class. Since Python doesn't use brackets, you need to match up the indents. Also, consider setting up the class constructor to have those variables as arguments (i.e. `(self, braun, brains, ...)`)

Comment: It should be `def __init__(self):`. Two underscores on either end.

Comment: Thank you Jacob K and Justin Ezequiel , really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell SuperHero() What hero's attributes are. You defining them outside the class just creates variables that have 0 relationships to the class. Here is what I suggest doing:

```
hero = SuperHero(superName = input("Please enter your Super hero name:"),brains = random.randint(1,20)
```

Then you can print off the attributes assigned to that Object "hero" you just created:

```
print("Your name is {}".format(hero.superName))
```

Comment: Thank you PJones98, appreciate you taking the time to help

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, is this your full code? Because the issue here is quite simple. You forgot to add the parameters to your class constructor. You assigned random numbers to your stats, but they're out of the object scope, meaning your Superhero won't access those variables unless you pass them as arguments to your constructor.

There's two ways to solve this:

A) You pass them as arguments in your constructor, so

```
class Superhero():
    #initializing our class and setting its atrributes
    def _init_(self, superName, power, braun, brains, stamina, wisdom, constitution, dexterity, speed):
        self.superName = superName
        self.power = power
        self.braun = braun
        self.brains = brains
        self.stamina = stamina
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.constitution = constitution
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.speed = speed

print("Please enter your Super Hero name: ")
superName = input('>')

power = random.randint(1,20)
braun = random.randint(1,20)
brains = random.randint(1,20)
stamina = random.randint(1,20)
wisdom = random.randint(1,20)
constitution = random.randint(1,20)
dexterity = random.randint(1,20)
speed = random.randint(1,20)

hero = Superhero(superName, power, braun, brains, stamina, wisdom, constitution, dexterity, speed)
```

And then you can print whatever you want.

B) Since your stats are all random, you can tell the constructor to assign them to random numbers, which shortens your code by a few lines, but won't let you assign your own stats when creating your object, like this:

```
class Superhero():
    #initializing our class and setting its atrributes
    def _init_(self, superName):
        self.superName = superName
        self.power = random.randint(1,20)
        self.braun = random.randint(1,20)
        self.brains = random.randint(1,20)
        self.stamina = random.randint(1,20)
        self.wisdom = random.randint(1,20)
        self.constitution = random.randint(1,20)
        self.dexterity = random.randint(1,20)
        self.speed = random.randint(1,20)

print("Please enter your Super Hero name: ")
superName = input('>')

hero = Superhero(superName)
```

Comment: Thank you Saulo Leão, appreciate you taking the time to respond. There will be more code, but at the moment this is it. I was testing along the way to make sure I was on the right track.